# Python xlwt simple wirting to sheet example

Tags: python, xlwt

Can someone explain why I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\Saul Ramirez\Documents\Python Scripts\DQforecast.py", line 156, in xlsOutput
forecastSheet.write(index, i, 'asdf')

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

for this function,

```
def xlsOutput(forecasts):
    os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Saul Ramirez\\Desktop')
    forecastWB = xlwt.Workbook()
    forecastWB_name = 'Forecasts' + str(datetime.date.today()) + '.xls'
    forecastSheet = forecastWB.add_sheet('Forecasst')
    i=0
    for rollRate in forecasts:
        for index in rollRate:
            forecastSheet.write(index, i, 'asdf')
        i=i+1

forecastWB.save(forecastWB_name)
```

Comment: Show the full traceback - the information about what part of xlwt is trying to call `len` is necessary.

Comment: Figured it out... Dumb question sorry!